# How to use Node.js to display mysql data in HTML with HBS

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

```
db.query("SELECT price FROM product", (req, res) => {
let price = res;
console.log(price);
});
```

Gives the following result in console:

```
[ RowDataPacket { price: 7.89 } ]
```

I then use the following code in HTML to display the "7.89" but nothing display in the front end:

```
<small>Price:{{price}} </small>
```

Comment: please add the javascript code that you use, have you debuuged if price is is a local or global variable

Answer (score 0):

Try this way for

```
 {{#each res}}
     <small>Price:{{this.price}} </small>
 {{/each}}
```

And in your querying logic in your controller, you need to pass the data to your view . Example :

// View Users

```
exports.view = (req, res) => {
  // User the connection
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE status = "active"', (err, rows) => {
    // When done with the connection, release it
    if (!err) {
      let removedUser = req.query.removed;
      res.render('home', { rows, removedUser });
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('The data from user table: \n', rows);
  });
}
```

Ref:
https://raddy.co.uk/blog/simple-user-management-system-nodejs-express-mysql-handlebards/